# Is this architecture definition OK? Multi-tier (Spring / Multi DB)

Tags: java, spring, architecture, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

Here´s the background, maybe some of the terms are incorrect, as I´m not an expert in this area:

> I applied several years ago the
>   following architecture, in order for
>   getting code reuse and kind-of
>   separation of concerns:
>
> - **Presentation Layer**: Using ASP.NET with C#. The web page logic is
>     programmed in here, but the business
>     logic is defined in a separate layer
> - **Model Definition Layer**: Groups all the business entities of the
>     system (i.e. Document, User, Folder).
>     There are no actions (methods beside
>     getters and setters) defined on the
>     object. It just represents a record
>     from a table (or a join of tables) in
>     the database
> - **Business Logic Layer**: The clases in here are named *"Engines"*, and they
>     have all the business rules
>     interaction for each Business entity
>     (i.e. DocumentEngine has all the
>     methods that represent the business
>     rules for handling Documents over the
>     system, like Adding, Deleting,
>     Updating, etc.). These methods use (as
>     parameters) and return Business entities (defined on Model definition) in many cases, in others just use/return primitives.
> - **Data access layer**: This layer retrieves the data (using the Data
>     Access Service) from database and
>     *convert* it into Business Entities (Creating an instance of an object defined in MDL and set its properties values with the corresponding field values retrieved from DB).
>     Like the Business Logic Layer, it uses
>     and return the Business entities or primitives
>     previously mentioned as a single
>     object or a collection of object
>     (using Generics)
> - **Data access service**: Using the Simple Factory Pattern, creates the
>     database connection according to the
>     specified parameters, so it can
>     retrieve the information from multiple
>     DB engines.
>
> OK then, when I need, for example a list of documents, I open the web page, the business rule is called with the proper parameters (i.e. the Folder Id for this case). Then the data access layer uses the DAS to query the database and converts the record(s) retrieved into Business entities (Defined in the MDL). This business entity (or collection of entities) is returned trough layers to the Presentation Layer.

Now, maybe this is not the best architecture, but it has worked very well to me, so now I´m trying to use the same approach but using Java with Spring MVC as the presentation layer, so I´ll have

- Presentation (Spring MVC)
- Model definition layer
- Business logic layer
- Data access layer
- Data access service (Database factory using JDBC)

The business requirements are "create an enterprise lightweight web application, that can be extended easily, connected to multiple DB (Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL) with minimal code changes, I18N supporting, ability of logging user activities, having several presentation modes (Web, Mobile) and looks very nice like Web2.0 applications XD"

What do you think? Is this a good architecture definition? Should I change something in order to comply with business requirements?

Thanks in advance for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the late 70s, just after the relational database started getting traction, and procedural programming was the thing to do, this would have been a fine architecture, adapted to use the newer web presentation layer.

In the early eighties the introduction of object orientation showed that separation of data and behavior leads to more coupling and less cohesion. Separation of model definition and business logic is a bad idea. It tends to arise from relational-database driven architectures, which tend to have no place to manage behavior.

Because of the RDBMS dominance, these architectures arise a lot. That doesn't make them good. The main issues arising are:

- repetition of the same concerns in multiple layers;
- bad data quality by separating validation functionality from the data it operates on;
- insufficient normalization because of bad join performance.

These issues limit the scalability of this architecture. A Domain-Driven Design performs better in these aspects.

In addition, your architecture doesn't tackle the consequences of mobile presentation adequately. Mobile is more than a smaller screen, it also involves a touch interface and limited connectivity (long delays, little bandwidth and caching, handling no connection).

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I started reading about DDD and after several pages, book chapters and so, I cannot understand 

a) Are really DTO's that bad?
b) How should I reflect Domain Objects changes to the DB?

I want to build an application, that in most of the cases will Insert new records, retrieve them, delete them and update them.. (i.e. the "Create Order" method will insert a new record on DB, the "Cancel order" method will delete or update some records)... How can all this operations doing also on the database?